# Display multiple records in datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have been googling all day and have not found the answer yet. It might be the keywords I'm searching for. In anyway, I am trying to display multiple records in a datagridview, not from the basic `select * from table` query. I am new in datagridviews

It's like in php, I can display multiple records of different id's in multiple divs, and the divs add up until all records have been fetched.

I need to fetch this data in order to print. Is there a way to do that in vb.net or should I do it in `mysql` instead? I am really not sure. Maybe a `for each` or `while` function but I don't know how.

I was thinking of making a `while loop` like this, but I am not sure:

```
Dim id as Integer = 0
while id < 100
    #query here
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    If da.Fill(ds, "Monthly Time Record") Then
       DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(id)
   End If
   id += 1
End While
```

Here's my code

```
    conn.ConnectionString = "it's a secret"
    conn.Open()
    Try
        Dim id As Integer = 0
        Dim query As String = "SELECT distinct date_format(cal.my_date,'%d') AS DAY, " +
                                "COALESCE((date_format(t.amin,'%h:%i %p')), '') AS 'AM IN', " +
                                "COALESCE((date_format(t.amout,'%h:%i %p')), '') AS 'AM OUT', " +
                                "COALESCE((date_format(t.pmin,'%h:%i %p')), '') AS 'PM IN', " +
                                "COALESCE((date_format(t.pmout,'%h:%i %p')), '') AS 'PM OUT' " +
                                "FROM " +
                                "    ( SELECT " +
                                "          s.start_date + INTERVAL (days.d) DAY  AS my_date " +
                                "      FROM " +
                                "          ( SELECT LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE('" & fromdate.Text & "', '%m/%d/%Y')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH " +
                                "                       AS start_date, " +
                                "                   LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE('" & fromdate.Text & "', '%m/%d/%Y'))  " +
                                "                       AS end_date " +
                                "          ) AS s " +
                                "          JOIN days  " +
                                "              ON  days.d <= DATEDIFF(s.end_date, s.start_date) " +
                                "    ) AS cal " +
                                "    LEFT JOIN attendance AS t " +
                                "        ON  t.d >= cal.my_date  " +
                                "        AND t.d  < cal.my_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY " +
                                "        and t.empID = '" & id & "'"
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        If da.Fill(ds, "Monthly Time Record") Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
        End If
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The result is like this (FOR A SINGLE datagridview):

```
Record for ID: 2
| DAY |  AM IN  |  AM OUT  |  PM IN  |  PM OUT |
|  1  | 8:00 AM | 12:00 PM | 1:00 PM | 5:00 PM |
|  2  | 8:05 AM | 12:30 PM | 1:15 PM | 5:30 PM |
|  3  | 8:00 AM | 12:15 PM | 1:05 PM | 4:45 PM |
..and so on until the end of the month
```

I'm trying to get this result (in multiple datagridviews):

```
Record for ID: 2
| DAY |  AM IN  |  AM OUT  |  PM IN  |  PM OUT |
|  1  | 8:00 AM | 12:00 PM | 1:00 PM | 5:00 PM |
|  2  | 8:05 AM | 12:30 PM | 1:15 PM | 5:30 PM |
|  3  | 8:00 AM | 12:15 PM | 1:05 PM | 4:45 PM |
...and so on until the end of the month

Record for ID: 3
| DAY |  AM IN  |  AM OUT  |  PM IN  |  PM OUT |
|  1  | 9:00 AM | 12:00 PM | 1:20 PM | 5:00 PM |
|  2  | 9:05 AM | 12:00 PM | 1:15 PM | 5:30 PM |
|  3  | 8:40 AM | 12:17 PM | 1:05 PM | 4:45 PM |
...and so on until the end of the month

Record for ID: 4
| DAY |  AM IN  |  AM OUT  |  PM IN  |  PM OUT |
|  1  | 6:30 AM | 12:01 PM | 1:40 PM | 5:10 PM |
|  2  | 6:05 AM | 12:32 PM | 1:15 PM | 5:19 PM |
|  3  | 5:40 AM | 12:10 PM | 1:00 PM | 5:01 PM |
...and so on until the end of the month
```

Comment: So each record has multiple rows?

Comment: Why not use a listbox for records and when the listbox item is selected have it fill the gridview?

Comment: yes it has multiple rows indeed, i am searching for listbox now.. don't know how to use that yet...

Comment: It's basically a gridview with one column

Comment: You need a DataGridView for each table the way you want to show the data... or combine the tables and then show it...

Comment: but i need to split them so i can print it out with header for each id, can i `for each` on a `datagridview` in order to achieve that?